# Save pdf file Memorystream in folder C#

Tags: c#, itext, memorystream

Im trying to make a function where i create a file pdf using memorystream but i dont know how to save this file memorystream on folder. How can i do this?

Here is my code:

```
        string beneficiarioRelatorio = service.RelatorioBeneficiarioService(numeroProtocolo);

        string matriculaRelatorio = service.RelatorioMatriculaService(numeroProtocolo);

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30f, 20f, 50f, 40f);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

         try
        {
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);

            pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

            Paragraph titulo = new Paragraph("Comprovante de solicitação de serviço eletrônico", fontTextBold);
            titulo.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            titulo.SpacingBefore = 50;
            titulo.IndentationLeft = 65;

            document.Add(titulo);
        }
        catch (DocumentException de)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
        }

        document.Close();

        stream.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        //return File(stream, "application/pdf", "Relatorio_Solicitacao_Servico_Eletronico.pdf");
        save file stream on folder?...
```

Comment: If you want the PDF to be saved to disk, just use a FileStream instead of a MemoryStream.

Comment: Do you want to save it directly to the local filesystem or do you want to return it as file on your endpoint as your code suggests?

Comment: just save this file in the server folder.

Answer (score 0):

File.WriteAllBytes("Filename.pdf", stream.ToArray());